# Cycle through windows in KDE on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kde

I just switched from Gnome to KDE on Ubuntu 14.04. Is there a keyboard shortcut to cycle through applications in KDE, such that if the same application has multiple open windows, only the first is shown in the switcher?

I see that I can use Alt+Tab to walk through all windows, but if I have a lot of windows open for a single application, I have to step through all of those windows.

Also, the task switcher in the bottom panel seems to work as I want, except that there is no keyboard shortcut. I have to move the mouse down to the panel and click on the tab.

Comment: What does alt+grave (below esc) do?

Comment: It does nothing, but I was planning to use it for `"Walk Through Windows of Current Application"` since that is how it works in Gnome/Unity..

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if that was already set up as that or if it did something different :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System settings > Workspace Appearance and Behaviour > Window Behaviour > Task Switcher > Content > Only one window per application

I'm not sure what you mean about the task switcher at the bottom, but you sholuld probably open anoter question for that.

[image]